# Is it possible to have a different application name for 32 bit v 64 bit with MFC?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

Is it possible to have a different application name for 32 bit v 64 bit?

[image]

I would like my application name to state (32 bit) or (64 bit) respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can use a conditional `#ifdef ... #else ... #endif` block in your `.rc` file, so you'll probably have to manually edit it, or put your `VERSIONINFO` block into an `.rc2` file that's included by the main `.rc`.

Like this:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
    FILEFLAGSMASK   VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
    FILEFLAGS       0
    FILEOS          VOS__WINDOWS32
    FILETYPE        VFT_APP
    FILESUBTYPE     0
    {
        BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
        {
            BLOCK "080904b0"
            {
                //...
                #ifdef _WIN64
                VALUE "FileDescription",  "My Application: 64-bit\0"
                #else
                VALUE "FileDescription",  "My Application: 32-bit\0"
                #endif
            }
        }
    }
```

But note, the resource compiler doesn't automatically define the `_WIN64` macro, so you'll need to add it (or something similar) as a *platform-specific* property:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show me what exactly should go in the external file? As I need to be able to edit other resources like normal.

Comment: @Andrew Are you generally familiar with the use of `rc2' files? I no longer use the 'visual' aspects of the resource editor (do everything manually, in the text editor), but I think you just need to create a new item in the project called something like "Version.rc2". Then, in the resource editor, somehow include that file. (IIRC, most of the  'template' apps give you a dummy `rc2` file - or they used to, at least.)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Sorry, I messed up the formatting of my comment and it's now too late to edit. I can re-post, if you need further info.

Comment: It is OK. I did have a rc2 file and just moved it in there. :) What I don't understand though is why "Default Apps" in Windows 10 still lists "Meeting Schedule Assistant MFC Application". I was hoping it would list the new names from version info.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That *may* be a Windows caching issue. Icons don't always change on EXE files immediately after you change them in the project and rebuild. Could be a similar issue.

Comment: Yes, I just found it in here `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache`. That will sort out eventually?

Answer (score 1):

The IDE has a [macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019) defined already `PlatformShortName=x86|x64`. To use that in the resource file:

- define a macro in project settings under Resources / General / Preprocessor Definitions for all configurations and platforms as

```
    "TARGET=\"$(PlatformShortName)\""
```

- edit the `.rc` file as text and edit the `VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO` section to replace

```
    VALUE "FileDescription", "SomeLabel"
```

with

```
    VALUE "FileDescription", "SomeLabel (" TARGET ")"
```

The file description compiled into the binary will now be `SomeLabel (x86)` or `SomeLabel (x64)`.

The modified `.rc` file will no longer be recognized by the IDE resource editor because of the macro presence, so you may want to move the edited `VERSIONINFO` to the `.rc2` file instead.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting alternative approach. Although I prefer (32 bit) / (64 bit) as the terminology.

Comment: No argument there. But this way if you decide to build for some platform other than x86/x64 tomorrow you won't have to change a thing ;-)

Comment: The TARGET definition, is it wrapped with quotes or do I just add a ; followed by your text without quotes?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle It should work either way. The IDE will wrap it in quotes on the RC command line, anyway, at least that's what I see here under Resources / Command Line.